# How to write a query with an average column in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, count, average

I would like to know if I can add an average column to this script whereby it averages the total number of inspections by the number of days. At the moment this report is showing 5 days worth of inspections. so I need the `averageinspection` column to divide the `totalinspection` by 5. is this possible?

```
SELECT     
    EstimName_String AS Inspector, 
    InspectionProcedureName AS inspection, 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalInspections
FROM
    UnitData_Vehicle
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY 
    InspectionProcedureName, EstimName_String
```

I would like to show this:

```
Inspector   Inspection  Totalinspections    Averageinspections
Joe Bloggs  Inspection         20               4
Micky Mouse Inspection        100               20
Jack and Jill   Inspection     50               10
```

Comment: Where does 5 come from, when DATEDIFF is looking for "1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    EstimName_String AS Inspector,
    InspectionProcedureName AS inspection,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalInspections,
    COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) AS AverageinspectionsPerDay
FROM
     UnitData_Vehicle
WHERE
    (DATEDIFF(day,      InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1)
GROUP BY
    InspectionProcedureName, EstimName_String
```

Comment: thank you, that looks like it, if I change the date range would the average change also?

Comment: @Tyrone2011: yes. As long as the divisor is the same DATEDIFF as the WHERE filter